# Python- Why are my outputs different than my inputs for a right triangle?

Tags: python

Why are my outputs different than my inputs, which should be the same for this program about determining the lengths and the angle of a right triangle?  Three length inputs, one angle input, and four functions are required for this assignment.  No math functions can be done in the main program, either.

Theoretically, shouldn't my printed adjacent length be the same as my **a** variable, and the same with my opposite, hypotenuse, and angle inputs to outputs?  Are my equations just incorrect or am I using wrong **math.** functions?

For clarity, a = adjacent length, h = hypotenuse, o = opposite

Inputs are:
4
3
5
53.13

The outputs I get are:
-4.984596089339195
0.3921757592513811
0.6435011087932844
0.6435011087932844

```
import math

a = float(input())
o = float(input())
h = float(input())
angle = math.degrees(float(input()))

def adjacent_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle):
adjacent_length = math.cos(angle) * h
return adjacent_length

def opposite_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle):
opposite_length = math.sin(angle) * h
return opposite_length

def angle_with_h_and_o(h, o):
adjacent_angle = math.asin(o / h)
return adjacent_angle

def angle_with_a_and_o(a, o):
adjacent_angle = math.atan(o / a)
return adjacent_angle

print(str(adjacent_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle)))
print(str(opposite_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle)))
print(str(angle_with_h_and_o(h, o)))
print(str(angle_with_a_and_o(a, o)))
```

Comment: Remember to show your real code, because this definitely isn't what you're running (it's Python: indentation makes literally the difference between "the code runs" and "the code errors out immediately")

Comment: If you entered those numbers in that order, you swapped your opposite and adjacent sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigonometric functions like `math.cos` take the input angle in radians, so use `math.radians` to convert the angle in degrees to radians. Inverse trigonometric functions like `math.asin` return the angle in radians, so use `math.degrees` to convert the result to degrees.

In particular, do **not** call `math.degrees` to convert the input; it's already in degrees.

```py
angle = float(input())

def adjacent_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle):
    adjacent_length = math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * h
    return adjacent_length

def opposite_length_with_h_and_angle(h, angle):
    opposite_length = math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * h
    return opposite_length

def angle_with_h_and_o(h, o):
    adjacent_angle = math.asin(o / h)
    return math.degrees(adjacent_angle)

def angle_with_a_and_o(a, o):
    adjacent_angle = math.atan(o / a)
    return math.degrees(adjacent_angle)
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of the radians vs degrees functions.  I believe that solved the problem.  Thank you!